# React : button to download a file on my computer

Tags: java, reactjs, download, frontend, backend

I am trying to download a .zip files generated by my back-end on my front-end (React), I would like to know what is the best practice to achieve that ?

Should I just refer to the correct path in the front-end like :

```
<a href={myFile} download="My_File.zip"> Download Here </a>
```

or should I request it to my back-end, somehow ?

Answer (score 0):

> Should I just refer to the correct path in the front-end

Yes it just like this, you shouldn't do any additional request to the backend - that won't help you in any way.